# What is the best way to create a background Task for an ILogger

Tags: c#, .net-core, task, blazor-server-side, cancellation-token

I created a File ILogger provider. It has a background task that does the actual writing to disk so that a `Log()` call is not waiting for a disk write to complete.

What is the best way to create/manage this background task? I can put it in a `Task.Run()` that I then forget about. But that strikes me as problematic.

In addition, the `ILogger.Provider.Dispose()` is never called. I want the task to be disposed so it can close the file it has open.

And, when Dispose() is called, I need to end the loop inside the `Task.Run()`. Is it better in this case to just have a bool I set? Or should I use a CancellationToken?

Comment: Why not use a timer?  And then provide a .Flush implementation that dumps the existing batched logged entries to file.  

Or just use Serilog.

Comment: @AngryHacker I tried Serilog and gave up on it after it ate up 1-1/2 days of my time trying to get it working. Faster to go this route. As to the timer, I've had times where the app writes a log entry and then blows up 2 lines of code later. I want that last log entry in that case. (My Serilog problem was with the AzureBlob sink - which is what I really need. The FileLogger is to first create a simpler provider, then do the same for Azure BLOBs.)

Comment: So, you want an asyncronous file logger, basically? But with a dedicated Thread? If so, I'd actually use a dedicated Thread and not steal one from the pool. And if you want graceful shutdown, you need to create an api to enable the client to support that (i.e. some kind of "FlushAndClose()", that can be called on app exit and in global exception handlers).

Comment: ^^ If this is the "best" way to go, though ... I would not _claim_ it to be. What made you give up on Serilog, if I may ask?

Comment: Do you have any reason to make your own logger rather than using an existing logging framework? like NLog?

Comment: @Fildor I gave up on Serilog after spending 12 hours trying to get it's AzureBLOB sink to work and failing. I came to the conclusion it's faster to write my own. Any guidance on how best to create a dedicated background thread. That is owned by my Logger implementation. TIA

Comment: @JonasH I tried Serilog and after 12 hours of frustration decided to just roll my own. Also, doing this I'll learn the best way to create a background thread in Blazor and the issues around that. Something that I'll need to use for other needs.

Comment: Not sure what the problem was with Serilog, but it's reasonably simple to setup, particularly writing to disk.  I threw together a sample for setting it up in a console app: https://pastebin.com/iXF0wGBT

Comment: @AngryHacker I was able to get Serilog writing to disk very quickly. It eliminated all the standard logging which was a problem, but Serilog itself worked. But getting the AzureBLOB sink working - 12 hours of frustration, pages no longer rendering, and never working. That was a disaster.

Comment: *Seek objective answers*.  Instead of "what is the *best* way to ..." and "*should* I ..."  rephrase your question as "*how* can I ..." and clearly state your objectives and criteria for success.  Otherwise you leave it to other people's opinions about what it "best" or what they think you "should" do.  "_strikes me as problematic_" is not a clear description of your concern.

Comment: @Wyck I have never understood this "objective" requirement when "how can I" is asking the same thing - what in your opinion is the best way to resolve an issue.

Comment: @DavidThielen you likely want to ask "How can I implement a logger so that log messages are lazily recorded to a file without blocking the log caller." It seems like you've settled on an asynchronous producer-consumer approach where the producer logs message quickly in a queue in system memory, and then the consumer can write queued log messages to a file without blocking the producer. Asking how to manage and dispose a fire-and-forget Task and what loop to put it in phrases your issue as an XY problem. And asking for "best way" may launch discussion about pros and cons of logging frameworks.

Comment: @Wyck I think my question was pretty focused. Some responders may choose to speak to the larger question but that's their decision to step back and do so. And I don't mind when people do because sometimes they bring up good points. But I specifically asked "What is the best way to create/manage this background task" - very specific.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discussing this with a number of developers I respect, the consensus was two-fold. First, use a thread:

```
public void Start()
{
    _workerThread = new Thread(ProcessQueue)
    {
        IsBackground = true,
        Priority = ThreadPriority.BelowNormal
    };
    _workerThread.Start();
}
```

The second part was something I hadn't thought of. Use synchronous calls. No async/await, no Tasks. We're all so set on async everything we don't stop to think. But if the code in the thread is going to write to the log file, and that's the only thing it's doing, you want all that happening in the thread.

There's no advantage to creating tasks and there are disadvantages. So...

```
private void ProcessQueue()
{
    while (!_cancellationTokenSource.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _newItemEventSlim.Wait(_cancellationTokenSource.Token);

        var lines = new List<string>();
        while (_queue.TryDequeue(out var message))
            lines.Add(message);
        WriteLine(lines);

        Flush();

        _newItemEventSlim.Reset();
    }
}
```

`WriteLine()` and `Flush()` are both synchronous. Because what would you gain by having them be async?

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a thread safe queue. The logger puts logging messages on the queue, and one or more threads/tasks pick messages from the queue and writes them to disk. Dispose should make the queue stop accepting new messages, and wait for any already queued messages to be written.

There are many ways to write such a queue, a very simple alternative is to use a blockingCollection:

```
public class QueueExample<T> : IAsyncDisposable
{
    private readonly Task task;
    private readonly BlockingCollection<T> queue = new();

    public QueueExample() => task = Task.Run(DoProcessing);

    public void Add(T item) => queue.Add(item);

    private void DoProcessing()
    {
        foreach (var item in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
            // do processing
        }
    }

    public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        queue.CompleteAdding();
        await task;
    }
}
```

The the loop will stop once `CompleteAdding` has been called and all items have been processed.

But my recommendation would be to use an existing logging framework. This will do buffering like this for you, as well as many other things that can be useful when logging.

I have mostly experience with nLog, and that is fairly easy to setup. Add the nuget dependency and put a configuration in your app.config file, something like this should work for .net framework at least:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />
  </configSections>
  <nlog>
    <targets async="true">
      <target name="fileTarget"
              xsi:type="File"
              keepFileOpen ="true"
              openFileCacheTimeout ="30"
              fileName=".\Logs\Log-${date}.txt"/>
    </targets>

    <rules>
      <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileTarget" />
    </rules>
  </nlog>
...
```

And create your logger like

```
private static readonly Logger log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
```

Comment: Yes, I've got something very much like what you have in your answer. My question is where/how do I create the thread/task to run this in?

Comment: I would actually create a thread in the constructor of the provider, given you did something like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/custom-logging-provider

Comment: @Fildor If you write that as an answer, including setting Thread.IsBackground, I'll accept it as the answer.

Comment: @DavidThielen The constructor in my example does `Task.Run`. It would perhaps be better to either mark it as "LongRunning", or start a dedicated thread, but I wanted to keep the example short. But as mentioned, I would really recommend using an existing framework.

Comment: ^^ That's the exact reason why I did not write this as an answer in the first place. I really would feel like giving bad advice. It might work for you, but for most people it would probably be better to stick to the beaten path. That includes myself. I haven't implemented any of this myself. All I did was reading, so ... don't trust me.

Comment: @Fildor, JonasH - the reason I dropped Serilog was primarily that their AzureBlob sink caused my pages to not render. I don't want a library that can have that side effect. In addition their AzureBlob sink didn't work, and so that was a problem. It took me less time to write my own ILogger than it took trying & failing with Serilog.

Comment: See, if we are talking about this one: https://github.com/chriswill/serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage, it claims to have had about 3.8 million nuget dls and at the time of writing 15 open issues ... I don't know. I would expect it to work at least to some extent.

Comment: @Fildor Yep that's the one. [I provided a very simple example of it not working](https://github.com/chriswill/serilog-sinks-azureblobstorage/issues/105). And I agree with you - based on the number of downloads Serilog and the azureblobstorage sink should both work. But what I found was the most basic simple use - fails.

Comment: Good to post an issue. I can't wrap my head around that you should be the only one with that exact reproducible problem...